# How to convert and assign result of a linq query to a datatable?

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable

This is my code

```
    var s = from p in db.tblTotalFees
                where p.Class == ClassDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value && p.StudentID == Convert.ToInt32(StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue)
                select p;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

How can i convert p into a datatable and store it in dt???

Comment: You should look up an Entity Framework tutorial. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ee712907

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CopyToDataTable()` extension method which is described on MSDN [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096.aspx). Usage:

```
var selectedClass = ClassDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value;
int id = Convert.ToInt32(StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue);

var query = from p in db.tblTotalFees
            where p.Class ==  && selectedClass
                  p.StudentID == id
            select p;

DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable(); // here
```

Or you can use pure ADO.NET - create SqlCommand and fill table with [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: There is no CopyToDataTable() in my intellisense. Why??

Comment: @PratikSharma have you read MSDN article from link? By default there is only `CopyToDataTable()` extension for `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. But in your case you have sequence of custom business object. That MSDN article describes how to implement such method for custom business objects.